# Is there any way I can change only a specific directory color in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I only need to set a color that will only effect a particular directory not globally.

Comment: Directories don't have a concept of "color" at all. And bash doesn't know anything about which colors `ls` assigns to a thing -- that's 100% the business of your `ls` command, which is a completely independent executable, not part of bash.

Comment: Now, if you wanted to *filter* the output of `ls`, to change the color of a given directory, we could probably do that -- but it'd mean that every time you ran `ls`, it would be not just the original `ls` command but the filter running after it and changing its output.

Comment: Now, if this is specifically GNU `ls` that you're dealing with, you could perhaps make the entire filename an extension in the `dircolors` database. See https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dircolors-invocation.html

Comment: ...but again, that's ls being configured to "treat any file with name X differently", it's not attaching metadata to file-X saying that it should get a specific color regardless of its name.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - instead of 4 (enough long comment) - one valid answer? Your comments in fact _answers_ the question. :) (regardless of fact, that it isn't OK question for the SO)

Comment: @jm666, ...eh. We don't even know with certainty that color in `ls` is what the OP wants -- maybe they're actually asking about using bash to change color as represented in some graphical file manager that uses xattrs for metadata storage. I'm happier to just see this moved to SuperUser. That said, if you (or anyone else) want to transcribe my comments to an answer, click community wiki and I'll have no qualm.

Comment: I'm new to linux and I thought Directories has a concept of color. But thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bash in a terminal that supports colors and would like to change the default color for text output to the terminal (not specifically the output of ls) while inside this directory, there is one thing you could do.

The `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable can be set to execute a command just before printing the prompt.  You could use that to check for the current directory and change the terminal color (for instance by assigning the `PS1` variable with a prompt that contains non-displayable special codes for selecting a color or echoing said special codes).

`PROMPT_COMMAND` is documented in the Bash manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

As for how to assign colors, you should look that up if interested.

This solution may not be what you are looking for, will probably have side effects, and generally speaking, I am not sure it will be that useful changing terminal colors depending on the current directory.  The usual solution is to have a prompt that shows the current directory path (or at least the last portion of the path).

I use something similar to the above to change text color depending on which machine I am executing Bash on, as I use `ssh` a lot from one machine to another over several terminal windows, and color (on a black background) is a good way to remember what machine any given window is connected to.